# how to deploy express server api on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have an ubuntu droplet on digital ocean and I'm tyring to deploy a `nodejs/express` api. I used [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/14/nodejs-mongodb-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management) to make the api and it runs great on my local machine (MacOS). However, when I try to start the server on my droplet I get this error:

```
> node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 start /opt/loginAPI
> node ./server.js

/opt/loginAPI/_helpers/jwt.js:18
async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/loginAPI/server.js:6:13)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 start: `node ./server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/treetop/.npm/_logs/2019-04-26T18_59_02_737Z-debug.log
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have keywords `async` and `function` on the same line and the interpreter complains about unexpected word `function`, which means that it treats word `async` okay, but it doesn't recognize `async function` together. I guarantee that you have Node version 8+ locally and version less than 8 on your remote server. Node.js of such versions doesn't have a keyword `async` (because it doesn't support async/await natively), therefore it treats it like a variable or a property of `global` object. Of course it can't figure out, why you are using keyword `function` after that and exits :)

P.S. Keep in mind that Node 8 LTS ends very soon.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that makes sense. I have node 11.3 locally. I'll try updating on my droplet. Thanks

Comment: Finally got a chance to try it on my server. Updating node did the trick. Thanks!